# Is there any way to skip cutscenes in Kingdom Hearts?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I die a lot in Kingdom Hearts, especially during boss battles. Is there any way to skip the cutscenes that often occur before them? I am tired of seeing the same cutscene four or five times while I struggle with a particular boss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first game, no. This was a major gripe from fans about the game. They added it in for the Rereleased version, but that is Japan only. The ability is added in later games, however.